# "click 1 to get 1, click 2 to get 2"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can I fix it to click 1 to get 1 and click 2 to get 2?

```js
$(function() {
  $('div.abox > a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
$('div.abox').click(function() {
  $('div.abox').css('display', 'none');
  $('div.page').css('display', 'block');
  page();
});

var num = 1;
var p = {
  1: {
    'title': 'title1',
    'img': '1111',
    'explain': 'ex1'
  },
  2: {
    'title': 'title2',
    'img': '2222',
    'explain': 'ex2'
  },
  3: {
    'title': 'title3',
    'img': '3333',
    'explain': 'ex3'
  },
  4: {
    'title': 'title4',
    'img': '4444',
    'explain': 'ex4'
  }
}

function page() {
  var abox = $('div.abox > a');

  $("#title").html(p[num]["title"]);
  $("#img").html(p[num]["img"]);
  $("#explain").html(p[num]["explain"]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="abox">
  <a href="" onclick="page();">1</a>
  <a href="" onclick="page();">2</a>
  <a href="" onclick="page();">3</a>
  <a href="" onclick="page();">4</a>
</div>
<div class="page">
  <h2 id="title">title</h2>
  <div id="img">img</div>
  <p id="explain">explain</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Change `function page()` to `function page(num)` and in your `onclick` write `page(1);`, `page(2);` etc. - (you can then remove the variable declaration `var num = 1`)

Comment: There are nicer ways than that and there is more that could be improved in your code but this should at least make it work and you can continue from there. (I didn't submit this as full answer because it's a bit raw and just a hint and I don't have much time atm, but it may already help.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.text()` to get text of a tag which is clicked and then use same to show your values .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var p = {
  1: {
    'title': 'title1',
    'img': '1111',
    'explain': 'ex1'
  },
  2: {
    'title': 'title2',
    'img': '2222',
    'explain': 'ex2'
  },
  3: {
    'title': 'title3',
    'img': '3333',
    'explain': 'ex3'
  },
  4: {
    'title': 'title4',
    'img': '4444',
    'explain': 'ex4'
  }
}


$(function() {
  $('div.abox > a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).index() + 1) //or this way
    console.log($(this).data('id')) //or this way
    var num = $(this).text(); //or this way
    $("#title").html(p[num]["title"]);
    $("#img").html(p[num]["img"]);
    $("#explain").html(p[num]["explain"]);
  });
  $('div.abox > a:eq(0)').trigger('click')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="abox">
  <a href="" data-id='1'>1</a>
  <a href="" data-id='2'>2</a>
  <a href="" data-id='3'>3</a>
  <a href="" data-id='4'>4</a>
</div>
<div class="page">
  <h2 id="title">title</h2>
  <div id="img">img</div>
  <p id="explain">explain</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Parsing displayed text is never a good idea.  If you're taking the "store it in the html" approach (which *is* a good idea) then store it in a `data-` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion @freedomn-m :) I have added that as well in my answer .

Answer (score 0):

A better approach for this can be adding data-num to link and fetch it by $(this).attr('data-num') in on click function.

Comment: Please check out the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve your formatting.